# Perform action on seen/unseen messages with socket.io

Tags: socket.io, chat, messagebroker

What is the best practice to handle seen/unseen messages in a chat room application based on Nodejs/[SocketIO](https://socket.io)/React.

Consider User1 sends a message to a room. If another user has seen that message, notify all users that the state of message has been seen.

In my opinion using message brokers can be the better solution instead socket. I actually think that socket should only handle chat messages that are synchronously. but for seen/unseen status I prefer message brokers that are asynchronous. Are there any solutions or best practice in large scale applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you have currently tried, meaning that I can only advise solutions in order to achieve your aim.

To firstly identify that a message was seen, `IntersectionObserver` is an inbuilt API that detects when an element has entered the viewport, meaning that it is visible, therefore; obviously seen. I have added comments in the code below where you should add a function to call to the server that the message was seen, however, that's up to you to implement.

```js
const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  if (entry.isIntersecting) {
    // Send a message to the server that the user has viewed the message.
    // Eg. socket.emit('read-message', message.id)
    return
  }
}, {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0.1,
})
observer.observe(document.getElementById(message.id));
```

Additionally, there's no need to use message broker, as socket.io can handle simple interactions such as this.

You then need to send a message to the server that denotes the specified message ID was seen, then broadcast to every other client that the state was changed, and update it to read - if that's needed.

Comment: please let me know if there is similar thing available for React native also. I am building an chat application.